# How to pass multiple parameters through URL in tableau 10.0

Tags: tableau-api

I am working on tableau 10.0. And I am trying to download workbook with the help of "tabcmd" command.  So for that I am  passing two date parameters for date range(start date & End date). 
I am trying the same  by following way:

Command:

**tabcmd export  "Workbook/SheetName?StartDate=2013-12-2900:00:00&EndDate=2014-03-1423:59:59" --fullpdf  -f "D:\Test\Report1.pdf" --no-certcheck**

But it is returning workbook with default values(which I have set during publishing workbook) and not as per the values that  I am trying to pass.

Same process I have achieved with tableau 9.3 with above syntax

But I am unaware of how to achieve same in Tableau 10.0. So I would like to seek your help regarding the same

Comment: Have you created the parameter in the tableau? Make sure the parameter name is case sensitive in tableau.

Comment: Yes I've checked that.Everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got solution.

In such case if you have space in parameter name like(**Start Date &End Date**) then you have to use %20 in place of space that is **Start%20Date** & **End%20Date** and 
Date format  should be **'yyyy-mm-dd'**